# Devel::Cover HTML output

Tags: perl, devel-cover

I am playing around with Devel::Cover to see how well our test suite is actually testing our codebase. I run all of our tests using `-MDevel::Cover` nothing seems to fail or crash, but the HTML output of the coverage table has entries like these for all of our Modules:

[image]

The number of `BEGIN`s listed seems to match the number of `use Module::X` statements in the source file, but really clutters the HTML output. Is there any way to disable this feature? I don't see any mention of it in the tutorial or the Github issue tracker.

Comment: The version that we have installed is `1.0.8` which is the latest release according to the README.

Comment: I think you mean `1.08`, which is the latest on CPAN.  How do you run it?  Do you use `cover`?  Show relevant code/commands.

Comment: Yes sorry, that is what I meant. I run our entire test suite with prove then call cover: `PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover prove -r -s lib/ && cover`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that "use" is "exactly equivalent to"

```
BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
```

(See [perldoc -f use](https://perldoc.pl/functions/use).)

And then "BEGIN" is basically the same as "sub BEGIN" - you can put the "sub" there if you want to.  See `perldoc perlmod`.

So what you really do have is a subroutine, and that is what `Devel::Cover` is reporting.

Like many parts of `Devel::Cover`, the details of perl's implementation, or at least the semantics, are leaking through.  There is no way to stop this, though I would be amenable to changes in this area.